# Remove polyline vertex outside polygon in Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, line, arcgis-pro, vertices

I am trying to remove polyline vertex which are outside the buffer polygon and not creates new vertex on intersection.

[image: Wrong]

I found a script which remove vertex but inside polygon. What is more it creates new vertex on intersection. It may help with this task.

[image: Wrong output]

```
import itertools, arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
line_FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
poly_FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

#clone input lines to memory for fast processing
temp = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(line_FC, "in_memory/temp")

polygons = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(poly_FC, arcpy.Geometry())

for poly in polygons:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(temp, ["SHAPE@"]) as uCursor:
        for line in uCursor:
            line = line[0]
            diff = line.difference(poly)
            #if the two lines are not equal, that means it intersected the polygon
            if not line.equals(diff):
                #the result of geometry.difference() is a multipart line of only those
                #parts that lie outside the polyon
                parts = diff.getPart()

                #if parts is empty that means the line is completely within the polygon
                #i.e., no difference
                if parts:
                    #We'll need to "join" the end of part1 to the beginning of part2
                    #so we'll just flatten the list of lists
                    joined = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(parts))

                    #and create a new polyline object to update the shape
                    poly_trimmed = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array(joined))
                    uCursor.updateRow([poly_trimmed])

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(temp, output)
```

Is there a way to do it in arcpy? I am using ArcGIS Pro 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something along these lines.

```
for points in parts:
    if not arcpy.Point(points.X, points.Y).within(poly):
         del points
```

I didn't test this out or anything, just a few thoughts I had.

Comment: Sorry but i can not get geometry from array